# how to reload supplementary view in collectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Is there an easy way to reload the suppplementary view only in a UICollectionViewFlowLayout? I don't want to reload the whole thing. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After reviewing the documentation, I'm not sure about reloading an individual supplementary view, but you can use `reloadSections:` to update 1 or more sections in the UICollectionView. ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177-CH1-SW39)) So when a section header needs updating, you can call:

Objective-C:

```
[self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)]];
```

Swift:

```
self.collectionView?.reloadSections(IndexSet(0 ..< 3))
```

Which happens to call:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       //Place logic for handling update here...
}
```

Comment: Saw many answers, this worked best for me when having the collectionview backed by a NSFetchedResultsController. Thanks

Comment: @Vitalii, see my revision for better fidelity to the objective-c code (with a range instead of an array). Also, collectionView is an optional in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to change the layout or size of the supplementary view from the Controller, use`[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`.If you want to refresh the supplementary view only,use `[supplementaryView setNeedsDisplay]`.Use both if the supplementary view is complex and/or will change its dimensions.

Comment: I can confirm `setNeedsDisplay()` works, especially for when you need to change the style of a view, like its color, text, image, etc. If your viewcontroller uses `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol, use the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method to save the `IndexPath` object to a viewcontroller variable and then use `yourCollectionView.supplementaryView()` to fetch it to refresh the view