# How to reload data only for supplementary view in collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is there a way to reload only header/footer data in collectionView? If I call collectionView.reloadData(), this will reloads whole collectionView so I'm trying to see if there is a way just to reload header data or footer data.

I look at this thread but it only shows how to reload section and header view not data. [Thread link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289669/how-to-reload-supplementary-view-in-collectionview)

Comment: you need to change the data in the data source before reload the header view..

Comment: I can do that but I just don't know the method to call to reload data for header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reload supplementary view in collectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289669/how-to-reload-supplementary-view-in-collectionview)

Comment: you can use visibleSupplementaryViews of UICollectionView method to get visible header and footer views. and update it.